# Power control widget shown for a short moment when updating my own widget via AppWidgetManager, what's the problem?

Tags: android, controls, widget

I've got a problem when updating my widget manually via AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget.
Platform is Android 2.2.

**Here's the code:**
I declared the widget additionally to an existing Activity in the Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".Widget" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget" />
</receiver>
```

The widget-class was declared in Widget.java:

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    int use_static_ip;
    RemoteViews remoteViews;

    try {
        use_static_ip = Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.WIFI_USE_STATIC_IP);
        if (use_static_ip == 0) { //DHCP
            remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_dhcp);
        } else { //static IP
            remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_static);
        }
        Intent call_activity = new Intent(context, StaticIPToggle.class);
        PendingIntent pending_call_activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, call_activity, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_icon, pending_call_activity);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
    } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

In the existing activity I added some lines to manually update the widget:

```
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), Widget.class);
        int[] ids = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(componentName);
        Intent update_widget = new Intent();
        update_widget.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
        update_widget.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(update_widget);
```

But now I have this bug:
If the widget is onClicked, it shows the energy-settings-widget for a short period (~0,5sec-1sec) before the desired widget is shown.

Here a screenshot of this issue (sequence from left to right): https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHkjw.jpg

First there's the widget as in the left picture, then changes to the middle picture and either stays there or changes to the right picture after ~0,5-1sec.

Unfortunately I can't see any mistake in the code, do you?

Hopefully you can help me to fix this problem ;)
Thanks in advance,
regards, Oli

Comment: Wow, I'm having the same issue; good to see it isn't just me, it's a difficult issue to describe.  I get the bug with an HTC EVO 4G running a custom 2.2 ROM, but not in the emulator.  The issue also doesn't happen with a Samsung Galaxy S.  Anyone out there have a solution?  Been struggling with this for a while.

Comment: I have seen this by testing the scrollablecontacts-widget with sources being [here](http://code.google.com/p/scrollablecontacts/) in a custom launcher trying to add the widget for many contacts. It may be related to your code taking too long to load the widget-content, maybe do the loading in a service started from the widget-class?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I solved it by manually updating the widget NOT through the broadcast, but by directly calling [AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(ComponentName, RemoteViews)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#updateAppWidget%28android.content.ComponentName,%20android.widget.RemoteViews%29) instead, from an AsyncTask.

Try this inside of your Widget class:

```
/**
 * Asynchronously builds views and updates the widget.
 */
private static class UpdateWidgetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, RemoteViews> {
    private AppWidgetManager mAppWidgetManager;
    private Context mContext;

    private UpdateWidgetTask(AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, Context context) {
        mAppWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected RemoteViews doInBackground(Void... params) {
        DebugLog.d(TAG, "Asynchronously updating widget.");
        RemoteViews views = buildUpdate(mContext);
        return views;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(RemoteViews views) {
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(mContext, Widget.class);
        mAppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, views);
    }
}

/**
 * Asynchronously updates all widgets of this type. This is the fastest way to update the widget.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 */
public static void updateWidget(Context context) {
    new UpdateWidgetTask(AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), context).execute();
}
```

Then update by calling Widget.updateWidget(this) from your activity.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same programatic way to manually update the widget as you did (From [Is it possible to throw an intent for APPWIDGET_UPDATE programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570146/is-it-possible-to-throw-an-intent-for-appwidget-update-programmaticall)) and found this to be the exact cause of the issue.

This still happens on 4.2 and 2.3, Official and Unofficial ROMS (Touchwiz goes absolutely wild when this happens).

The only way I could fix this was to remove the whole update involving the broadcast and to update the widget remotely by sending a regular `Broadcast` to the Widget Provider and calling

```
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,AvailabilityWidgetProvider.class);
AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(thisWidget,views);
```

from within `onReceive`

(This works for me as the my widgets are identical)

This way, the issue seemed to not occur and I could update the widget remotely.
Old question, I know, but deserves an answer as this was all I could find on this weird issue.