# asynctask not completeing onUpdate Android Widget

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-widget

Morning Everyone,
Trying to get an onclick event on a widget to work, problem is that a background asynctask isn't completed before the onUpdate function which sets the pending intent.  I have a little bit of familiarity with android but definitely still in the learning stage.  The testing I did in an actual activity works well and correctly and watching when the logs come in it is definitely a timing issue. Any help would be appreciated!!

```
public class SingleClickWanIP extends AppWidgetProvider {
private static final String TAG = "waninfo";

private String myURL;
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    Log.d(TAG,"started update: " + myURL);
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)  context.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
    String homessid = "\"MyRouterName\"";

    if (ssid.equalsIgnoreCase(homessid)){
        myURL = "192.168.1.106";
    }
    Log.d(TAG,"finished ssd check: " + myURL);
    String newURL = "http://"+myURL+":120";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(newURL);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.single_click_wan_ip);
    Log.d(TAG,"finished intent and remote views: " + myURL);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ibOrange, pendingIntent);
    Log.d(TAG,"finished on click pending: " + myURL);

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);
    }
    Log.d(TAG,"finished onUpdate: " + myURL);
}



@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    ProcessURL process = new ProcessURL();
    process.execute("https://www.dropbox.com/link to get external ip value/wanip.txt?raw=1");
    Log.d(TAG,"started process: " + myURL);

}

private class ProcessURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.d(TAG,"started background");
        return GET(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        myURL = result;
        Log.d(TAG,"finished and set myURL variable: " + myURL);
    }



    private  String GET(String url){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            // create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // make GET request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

            // receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // convert inputstream to string
            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }

    private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }
}
```

Little bit of background, I am cheap and don't want to pay for no-ip or something similar.  But I want to share my server access with friends and family and without having to tell them "yeah, just type in xx.xx.xx.xxx:120 to get there".  So server writes to my dropbox file the external ip, I have a shared link from dropbox that I use in this app to get the value, and then open up my server's site.  viola

---

### Edit

...and got it!  fumbling around I found this post about the strange behavior of the widget spontaneously switching which fixed that [spontaneous widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621786/power-control-widget-shown-for-a-short-moment-when-updating-my-own-widget-via-ap/18534005).  Then the click wouldn't work because I had to wrap the code in onupdate with an if since it wouldn't do to create a pending uri intent with a null as the url address.  So...copied the pending onclick intent to the onpostexecute process and now I am a bug in a rug.

Thanks for the leads, much appreciated!

### contents of onpostexecute:

```
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) gContext.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
            String homessid = "\"MyRouterName\"";

            if (ssid.equalsIgnoreCase(homessid)) {
                result = "192.168.1.106";
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "finished ssd check: " + result);
            myURL = "http://" + result + ":8080";

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(myURL);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(gContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(gContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.single_click_wan_ip);
            Log.d(TAG, "finished intent and remote views: " + myURL);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ibOrange, pendingIntent);
            Log.d(TAG, "finished on click pending: " + myURL);

            ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(gContext, SingleClickWanIP.class);
            gappWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, views);

            Log.d(TAG,"finished and set myURL variable: " + myURL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would request an update of the widget on `onPostExecute` of the asynctask since that is when you have the URL and you can now setup the pending intent correctly.

Use an intent with action AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE to request the widget update.

Comment: see my edits.  Not sure what I did wrong but now it spontaneously changes to the flashlight widget...

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is much safer to update the widget from an `IntentService` rather than from an `AsyncTask` started from your app widget provider.

`onEnabled` and `onUpdate` are supposed to complete within (maximum) 10 seconds.

I strongly recommend you to use the following code:

**SingleClickWanIP.java**

```
public class SingleClickWanIP extends AppWidgetProvider
{
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, ProcessURL.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context)
    {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, ProcessURL.class));
    }
}
```

**ProcessURL.java**

```
public class ProcessURL extends IntentService
{
    private static final String TAG = "waninfo";
    private String myURL;

    public ProcessURL()
    {
        super("ProcessURL__service");
        setIntentRedelivery(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent__)
    {
        myURL = GET("https://www.dropbox.com/link to get external ip value/wanip.txt?raw=1");
        Log.d(TAG,"finished and set myURL variable: " + myURL);

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)  getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
        String homessid = "\"MyRouterName\"";

        if (ssid.equalsIgnoreCase(homessid))
        {
            myURL = "192.168.1.106";
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"finished ssd check: " + myURL);
        myURL = "http://"+myURL+":120";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(myURL);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.single_click_wan_ip);
        Log.d(TAG,"finished intent and remote views: " + myURL);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ibOrange, pendingIntent);
        Log.d(TAG,"finished on click pending: " + myURL);


        // Update all widgets

        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        if(null != manager)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"Updating all widgets...");
            manager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(this,SingleClickWanIP.class), views);
            Log.d(TAG,"finished and set myURL variable: " + myURL);
        }
    }

    private  String GET(String url)
    {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try
        {
            // create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // make GET request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

            // receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // convert inputstream to string
            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

And add the following line within the `<application />` tag of your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<service android:name="[ADD-THE-PATH-TO-ProcessURL.java-HERE].ProcessURL" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" />
```